# how to print vietnamese in priter zebra imz220

Tags: zebra-printers

i use printer imz220 but  i can't print vietnamese. my zbl is "

```
^XA
^FX Top section with company logo, name and address.
^CI28
^CF0,30
^FO10,10^FDCấp Nước Đồng Nai^FS
^CF0,20
^XZ
```

"
but it don't printout

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the 0 font has those characters. Download the andale font and try the following:

^XA^CI28^CW1,E:ANMDS.TTF^LL230^PW600
^FO10,10^A1N,30,20^FDCấp Nước Đồng Nai^FS
^XZ

Comment: thanks banno. but i don't know how to download andale font and install it to printer. Could you instruct me. thanks very much

Comment: Download Zebra Setup Utilities and follow the manual instructions for loading a font. You may have to change the font name above depending on what font you choose. Here is a link I found on google which may help: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7889